# Checking the values in the string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on my keyboard code to enter the keyboard numbers in the string to set up the numbers.

```
DIGIT_BUTTONS = range(58, 68)

if action.getId() in DIGIT_BUTTONS:
   self.EPG_Channel_Number += str(action.getId() - 58)
   self.getControl(413).setLabel('[B]' + self.EPG_Channel_Number + '[/B]')
```

When I press on the keyboard buttons 1,0,3 which added to 3 numbers in the string. Now I would like to check how many values I have got in the string.

Can you please show me an example how I can check how many values I have got in the string?

Comment: what is the string?

Comment: Here is the string `103`

Comment: `len(self.EPG_Channel_Number)` - presuming that's the string you want the length for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the lenght in a simple way:

```
len(self.EPG_Channel_Number)
```

Comment: Perfect, you are welcome, can accept the answer ;) @DanielEzekiel